# How do I delete one specific M2M relation between 2 Models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True)
```

How do I delete one specific M2M relation between them(not clear all of them), having access to both instances of Contact and Item involved ?

Comment: What do you mean? There is only one relation between the two. You delete it by removing `contacts` from `Item`. Or do you want to remove one row from the relationship table (that links one `Item` to one `Contact`? Then you do e.g. `Item.objects.get(pk=primary_key_of_item).contacts.remove(Contact.objects.get(pk=primary_key_of_contact))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rereading your question, it seems you want to delete the association between one `Item` object (`item`) and one `Contact` object (`contact`). To do so is easy:

```
item.contacts.remove(contact)
```